# QTextEdit: how to save images inserted with QTextCursor?

Tags: qt, qt4

I inserted several images into QTextEdit with QTextCursor, now how should I save this entire thing ?

My first thought was to iterate through all positions of QTextCursor, but I didn't find the proper interface to use.

Sample code in use:

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
cursor.insertImage(QImage ("/secure/Common/Pictures/icons/gimp.svg"));
ui->textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);

QTextDocument *document = ui->textEdit->document();
QStringList images;
QTextBlock b = document->begin();
while (b.isValid()) {
    for (QTextBlock::iterator i = b.begin(); !i.atEnd(); ++i) {
        QTextCharFormat format = i.fragment().charFormat();
        bool isImage = format.isImageFormat();
        if (isImage)
        {
            images << format.toImageFormat().name();
            qDebug() << document->resource(QTextDocument::ImageResource,
                                           QUrl(format.toImageFormat().name())).toByteArray().size();
        }
    }
    b = b.next();
}
```

Comment: Is it sufficient to save a reference to the images, or must the saved document be self-contained?

Comment: @Slavik81 must be able to be exported..I need to store them in database, or any other ways ? Just be able to insert and recover from some data is fine I think

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Quick-and-dirty solution**

Just call `document->toHtml()` and parse the `img` tags.

**Clean solution**

Iterate over all the `QTextFragment` in the text:

```
QStringList images;
QTextBlock b = document->begin();
while (b.isValid()) {
    for (QTextBlock::iterator i = b.begin(); !i.atEnd(); ++i) {
        QTextCharFormat format = i.fragment().charFormat();
        bool isImage = format.isImageFormat()
        if (isImage)
            images << format.toImageFormat().name();
    }
    b = b.next();
}
```

Warning: I didn't test this, it might not even compile.

Comment: It worked, but how do you get the data of a QResource ?  The doc says `The name refers to an entry in the application's resources file.`, but I didn't find a function to get the resource data

Comment: Tried this:  `QFile fp (":/"  + format.toImageFormat().name());                 fp.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); qDebug() << fp.readAll();`, got empty output; fp.errorString() was `Unknown error`

Comment: Actually you don't get QResources but a wholly different type of resource, which you should be able to access with `document->resource(QTextDocument::ImageResource, name)`.

Comment: Seems empty, `QVariant::toByteArray().size()` returns 0, I put my code in my question

Comment: That's because `QVariant::toByteArray` only works when the argument is a string or a ByteArray. Image resources are `QPixmap` or `QImage` depending on how they were constructed, so use `value<QPixmap>`/`value<QImage>`. More generally you can use `QVariant::typeName()` to find out the type of the contents of a `QVariant`.